# How to run before_save callback if no field is modified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have a virtual field "delete_picture to delete a paperclip attached file field:

```
class Paragraph < ApplicationRecord

  has_attached_file :picture, path: "....", url: " ...
  attr_accessor :delete_picture

  before_save do
    picture.clear if delete_picture=="1"
  end

end
```

in the form, I have a checkbox on `delete_picture` field, if user clicks on it and submmit, the picture is cleared **only if another field is changed too**, if not, the before_save callback is **not** executed.

So, how can I make callback runs, if only a `attr_accesor` field is modified?

The model is nested in another one:

Parent model:

```
class Menu < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :paragraphs, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :menu
  validates :paragraphs, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :paragraphs, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |obj| obj["content"].blank? and obj["picture"].nil? }


end
```

and the form, over menu, and fields_for over paragraphs

```
<%= form_for(@menu) do |f| %>
...
      <%= f.fields_for :paragraphs do |paragrafs| %>
      ....
        <%=paragrafs.check_box :delete_picture, class:"delete"%>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the form-field? Rails has some nice helpers that make sure a value gets passed through for a check-box even if they don't select it (because the default browser behaviour is to not do that). Seeing what you've got will help us determine what's happening with that. Ie I don't think you've got a problem in your callback, but in how/when the params are coming through

Comment: yes, here it is, thanks

Comment: Hmm, nothing obvious jumps out... can you show us what gets rendered in the html? (in case something weird is happening)? also - look in your console and/or logfile and show us what comes through in the `params` when you submit the form (and either do or don't choose a checkbox)?